# How to get data from gridview for raw data print in VB .Net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, desktop-application, vb.net-2010

I need help...

I have a data that is taken from the database with table items and I send it to be displayed on the grid view.

I want to retrieve data in gridview to make a raw print data that will be printed via dot printer matrix.

Can anyone help me to retrieve data on the gridview in the image ??

[gridview picture- data get from mysql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVZFE.png)

Comment: Is that really a `GridView`, which would mean that you are creating a WPF app?  If so then you should use the WPF tag.  If your app is actually Windows Forms then it must be a `DataGridView`, in which case you should use the right name for the control, in order to avoid confusion, and also use the Windows Forms tag.

Comment: Focusing on retrieving *strings*.  Printing a string is of course not a problem.  If you don't know how to access the cells of a gridview then google "wpf gridview get cell value".  Too many hits at SO to recommend the best one.